# Left only MAX value per group

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have got table like this:

| TransactionID | … | Cost | MaxCostPerGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ... | 1550 | 1550 |
| 2342 | ... | 1950 | 2000 |
| 2342 | ... | 2000 | 2000 |
| 4444 | ... | 600 | 600 |
| 4444 | ... | 400 | 600 |
| 4444 | ... | 500 | 600 |

**TransactionID** – not unique

 **…** - a lot of columns (30+)

**Cost** – could be different to one TransactionID

**MaxCostPerGroup** column shows max value for each TransactionID.

To continue working with data I need to bring table to the following form:

| TransactionID | … | Cost | MaxCostPerGroup |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | ... | 1550 | 1550 |
| 2342 | ... | 1950 | null |
| 2342 | ... | 2000 | 2000 |
| 4444 | ... | 600 | 600 |
| 4444 | ... | 400 | null |
| 4444 | ... | 500 | null |

Then I want to sum MaxCostPerGroup by date (for example). Problem is that I must save every row, I cannot just group by. In ‘…’ section a lot of unique information, that is why I want to left only one value per TransactionID in last column. How can I do it with SQL?

Many thanks.

Comment: Does your table have a field, or group of fields, which is unique? If not and you want to treat rows with the same values differently you have to use a procedure with a curser. You should definitely consider adding a primary key to you table both for data manipulation and efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Using your data, I got the max value by partitioning by `TransactionId` and adding a IF statement to add NULLs.

See query below:

```
WITH sample_data as(
    select '1234' as TransactionID, 1550 as Cost, 1550 as MaxCostPerGroup,
    union all select '2342' as TransactionID, 1950 as Cost, 2000 as MaxCostPerGroup,
    union all select '2342' as TransactionID, 2000 as Cost, 2000 as MaxCostPerGroup,
    union all select '4444' as TransactionID, 600 as Cost, 600 as MaxCostPerGroup,
    union all select '4444' as TransactionID, 400 as Cost, 600 as MaxCostPerGroup,
    union all select '4444' as TransactionID, 500 as Cost, 600 as MaxCostPerGroup
),
get_max as (
    select TransactionId,
        Cost,
        max(MaxCostPerGroup) OVER (PARTITION BY TransactionId) as max_per_id
    from sample_data
),

add_null as (
    select TransactionId,
        Cost,
        max_per_id,
        if (Cost = max_per_id, max_per_id, NULL) as MaxCostPerGroup
    from get_max
)

select TransactionId,Cost,MaxCostPerGroup from add_null
```

Output:

[image]